# Qualitative descriptions of probability distributions?

Tags: probability

We are given the following scenarios:

a) The number of typographical errors in a 1000 page book, if an average page has about 4000 characters and about 90% of the pages have no errors at all?

Is this a Poisson distribution? How would I find the expected number of errors?

b) The number of test subjects who improve in a clinical trial with 20 participants drawn at random from a population if the treatment is effective for about 20% of subjects.

Is this a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the binomial distribution is the proper one, but if n is large and p is small, it can be very well approximated by the poisson-distribution with parameter np.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard to use a Poisson model for the first problem. Let the number of errors in a randomly selected page be $X$.

Suppose that $X$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. We are told that $\Pr(X=0)=0.9$. Thus $e^{-\lambda}=0.9$, and therefore $\lambda=-\ln(0.9)$.

The number of errors in the book has Poisson distribution with parameter $1000\lambda$. This would be the mean number of errors in the book.

A Binomial model would also work well, if we work at the level of **characters**. In principle, it is better, since a character is indivisible. The computation becomes more complicated.

For the second problem, yes, a Binomial model is appropriate.